# Mysql: Sum by current date + 30 days

Tags: mysql

Table structure:

```
id int
revenue float
date date
```

I would like to SUM the revenue and group the result by date +30 days starting from a specific date until current date.

So i have data starting from 2015-01-05 so i would like to get the sum of the revenue starting from 2015-01-05 and each group should have +30 days like

```
2015/01/05 - 2015/02/04 
2015/02/04 - 2015/03/06
2015/03/06 - 2015/04/05
etc
```

So i want the result to be grouped in 30 days periods (not months)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
GROUP BY FLOOR(DATEDIFF(date, '2015-01-05')/30)
```

`DATEDIFF` calculates the days between two dates. Then we divide by `30` to reduce them to 30-day blocks, and use `FLOOR` to remove the fraction.